# facebook auto publish post using php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a PHP script that shares posts automatically on Facebook. My script works perfectly when I execute directly from the browser, but when I enable cron jobs it basically executes the file but doesn't share on my Facebook wall. I don't know exactly what's the issue behind it. Here is my script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('facebookapi/site-primary-config.php');
require_once('facebookapi/facebook.php');

// configuration
 $appid = 'xxxxx';
 $appsecret = 'xxxxx';
 $pageId = 'xxxx';

//Get Load from Social Video ID 
$get_link_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT
tblmevids.vid_code as video_tbl_code,
tblmevids.vid_title as video_tbl_title,
tblmevids.vid_seo_descp as video_tbl_description,
tblmevids.vid_slug as video_tbl_slug,
tblsocial_share.vidsc_code as vid_social_code,
tblsocial_share.vid_fb_sstat as vid_social_fb_status
FROM tblmevids
JOIN tblsocial_share
ON tblmevids.vid_code = tblsocial_share.vidsc_code
WHERE tblmevids.vid_act_stat = '1' AND tblsocial_share.vid_fb_sstat = '0' LIMIT 1");
$count_sql = mysqli_num_rows($get_link_sql);
$link_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_link_sql);
$selected_video = $link_row['video_tbl_code'];
$selected_title = $link_row['video_tbl_title'];
$selected_description = $link_row['video_tbl_description'];
$selected_slug = $link_row['video_tbl_slug'];
    if($count_sql > 0 ) {
        //Grab Video Details
            $msg = $selected_title.' - Watch Now at '.$site_baseurl.'watch?v='.$selected_video;
            $title = $selected_title;
            $uri = $site_baseurl.$selected_slug;
            $desc = $selected_description;
            $pic = $site_baseurl.'video_thumbs/'.$selected_video.'.jpg';
            $action_name = 'Go to mywebsite.com';
            $action_link = 'http://mywebsite.com';

            echo $msg."<br/>".$title."<br/>".$uri."<br/>".$desc."<br/>".$pic."<br/>".$action_name."<br/>".$action_link."<br/>";

            //Start FB Sharing
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $appid,
                'secret' => $appsecret,
                'cookie' => false,
            ));
            $user = $facebook->getUser();
            // Contact Facebook and get token
            if ($user) {
             // you're logged in, and we'll get user acces token for posting on the wall
                try {
                $page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");
                if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
                        $attachment = array(
                        'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
                        'message' => $msg,
                        'name' => $title,
                        'link' => $uri,
                        'description' => $desc,
                        'picture'=>$pic,
                        'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
                    );

                    $status = $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", "post", $attachment);
//Update Social Table Start
$get_perfect_status = '1';
$updates = array();
    if (is_numeric($get_perfect_status))
      $updates[] = '`vid_fb_sstat` ="'.$get_perfect_status.'"';
      $updates = implode(', ', $updates); 
      $sql = "UPDATE `tblsocial_share` SET $updates WHERE vidsc_code = '$selected_video'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
                echo "Shared on Facebook and updated sucessfully";
        } else {
                echo "There was a problem in sharing";
        }
//Update Social Table End
                     } else {
                     $status = 'No access token recieved';
                     }
                     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                     error_log($e);
                     $user = null;
                     }
                     } else {
                     // you're not logged in, the application will try to log in to get a access token
                     header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions,manage_pages'))}");
                     }

                    echo $status;

    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it in a crons job it is not getting a user, when you run it in your browser, you are logged into facebook on your browser. The way to fix this would be to get your user id from facebook and change

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

to
    $user = 'xxxxx';

you can get your user ID with a simple echo statement after $user = $facebook->getUser();

```
echo $user."\n";
```

Comment: still not working, i replaced with my id but the same thing happen again